# Specify which positions in an array a thread access

Tags: c, openmp

I'm trying to create a program that creates an array and, with OpenMP, assigns values to each position in that array. That would be trivial, except that I want to specify which positions an array is responsible for.

For example, if I have an array of length 80 and 8 threads, I want to make sure that thread 0 only writes to positions 0-9, thread 1 to 10-19 and so on.

I'm very new to OpenMP, so I tried the following:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define N       80

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int nthreads = 8, tid, i, base, a[N];

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        base = ((float)tid/(float)nthreads) * N;
        for (i = 0; i < N/nthreads; i++) {
            a[base + i] = 0;
            printf("%d %d\n", tid, base+i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program, however, doesn't access all positions, as I expected. The output is different every time I run it, and it might be for example:

```
4 40
5 51
5 52
5 53
5 54
5 55
5 56
5 57
5 58
5 59
5 50
4 40
6 60
6 60
3 30
0 0
1 10
```

I think I'm missing a directive, but I don't know which one it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to ensure that things work the way you want is to have a loop of just 8 iterations as the outer (parallel) loop, and have each thread execute an inner loop which accesses just the right elements:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(j)
   for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
     for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
       a[10*i+j] = 0;
       printf("thread %d updated element %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), 8*i+j);
     }
   }
```

I was unable to test this right now but I'm 90% sure this does exactly what you want (and you have "complete control" over how things work when you do it like this). However it may not be the most efficient thing to do.  For one thing - when you just want to set a bunch of elements to zero, you want to use a built in function like `memset`, not a loop...

Comment: This worked. I'm aware it's not the right way to do it with OpenMP, I guess I should have mentioned in the description that I need this controlled behavior because it'll work as test for another tool I'm developing - this won't go into any production program.

Comment: @iomartin - your proposed edit was correct, and unjustly rejected. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a fair bit.  The directive

```
#pragma omp parallel
```

only tells the run time that the following block of code is to be executed in parallel, essentially by all threads.  But it doesn't specify that the work is to be shared out across threads, just that all threads are to execute the block.  To share the work your code will need another directive, something like this

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for 
    ...
```

It's the `for` directive which distributes the work across threads.

However, you are making a mistake in the design of your program which is even more serious than your unfamiliarity with the syntax of OpenMP.  Manual decomposition of work across threads, as you propose, is just what OpenMP is designed to help programmers avoid. By trying to do the decomposition yourself you are programming against the grain of OpenMP and run two risks:

1. Of getting things wrong; in particular of getting wrong matters that the compiler and run-time will get right with no effort or thought on your part.
2. Of carefully crafting a parallel program which runs more slowly than its serial equivalent.

If you want some control over the allocation of work to threads investigate the `schedule` clause.  I suggest that you start your parallel region something like this (note that I am fusing the two directives into one statement):

```
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(a,base,N)
{
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a[base + i] = 0;
}
```

Note also that I have specified the accessibility of variables.  This is a good practice especially when learning OpenMP.  The compiler will make `i` private automatically.

As I have written it the run-time will divide the iterations over `i` into chunks, one for each thread.  The first thread will get `i = 0..N/num_threads`, the second `i = (N/num_threads)+1..2N/num_threads` and so on.

Later you can add a `schedule` clause explicitly to the directive.  What I have written above is equivalent to

```
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(a,N) schedule(static)
```

but you can also experiment with

```
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(a,N) schedule(dynamic,chunk_size)
```

and a number of other options which are well documented in the usual places.

Answer (score 0):

`#pragma omp parallel` is not enough for the `for` loop to be parallelized.

Ummm... I noticed that you actually try to distribute work by hand. The reason it does not work is most probably becasue of racing conditions on computing the parameters for the `for` loop.

If I recall properly any variables declared outside of the parallel region are shared among threads. So ALL threads write to `i`, `tid` and `base` at once. You could make it work with appropriate `private`/`shared` clauses.

However, a better ways is to let OpenMP distribute the work.
This is sufficient:

```
#pragma omp parallel private(tid)
{
  tid = omp_get_thread_num();
  #pramga omp for
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    a[i] = 0;
    printf("%d %d\n", tid, i);
  }
}
```

Note that `private(tid)` it makes a local copy of `tid` for each thread, so they do not overwrite each other on the `omp_get_thread_num()`. Also it is possible to declare `shared(a)` because we want each thread to work on the same copy of table. This is implicit now. I believe iterators should be declared private, but I think `pragma` takes care of it, not 100% how it is this specific case, when its declared outside the parallel region. But I'm sure you can actually set it to `shared` by hand and mess it up.

EDIT: I noticed original underlying problem so I took out irrelevant parts.